# how to query postgres jsonb for following json and make it available as part of the result

Tags: postgresql

I have the following record as a jsonb field in a PG13 table

```
meta 
{"subscriptions": [{"location_id": 14555, "practice_area_id": 39, "monthly_quota_views": 300, "remaining_views": 300}, 
                   {"location_id": 14832, "practice_area_id": 39, "monthly_quota_views": 250, "remaining_views": 250}, 
                   {"location_id": 17793, "practice_area_id": 39, "monthly_quota_views": 700, "remaining_views": 700}]}
```

I'd like to query for location_id: 14555, practice_area_id: 39 and having remaining_views > 0. Also, I'd like to return the selected hash from the array as part of the result (if possible).

I have

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 
meta->'subscriptions' @> '[{"location_id":14555}]' and 
meta->'subscriptions' @> '[{"practice_area_id":39}]';
```

but how would I check for remaining_views > 0 and return that selected hash as part of the result? Is there a less bulky way of writing this query? Thanks

Comment: What do you mean with "selected hash"? I don't see a key named `hash` in your sample data. What if more then one array elements matches your conditions?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name yes, you are right. so the array of selected subscriptions and yes possible there could be multiple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect by "*return the selected hash from the array*" you refer to the **object** that is contained in the `subscriptions` array.

There are two ways to do this:

- use `jsonb_array_elements` to get the individual objects:

  ```
  SELECT *
  FROM pg13,
  LATERAL jsonb_array_elements(pg13.meta -> 'subscriptions') el
  WHERE el->>'location_id' = '14555'
    AND el->>'practice_area_id' = '39'
    AND (el->>'remaining_views')::int > 0
  ```
- use a json path query:

  ```
  SELECT *, jsonb_path_query(meta, '$.subscriptions[*] ? (@.location_id == 14555 && @.practice_area_id == 39 && @.remaining_views > 0)')
  FROM pg13
  ```

Comment: We're changing what we store to be a hash for `remaining_views` like `remaining_views: {"1": 100, "2": 100, "3":100},`. Do you know how I could adjust your first query? Thinking something like   `AND el->>'practice_area_id' = '39'
  AND (el->>'remaining_views'->>'1')::int > 0;` but this is not working. Thx for help

Comment: `->>` casts to text, `->` keeps jsonb so you can chain further: `AND (el->'remaining_views'->>'1')::int > 0`. Or just go for the path access operator `(el #>>'{remaining_views,1}')::int > 0`. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html

Answer (score 1):

You can use a JSON path expression to filter the desired elements and also return only those:

```
select jsonb_path_query_array(meta, '$.subscriptions[*] ? (@.location_id == 14555 && @.practice_area_id == 39 && @.remaining_views > 0)')
from the_table
where meta @? '$.subscriptions[*] ? (@.location_id == 14555 && @.practice_area_id == 39 && @.remaining_views > 0)';
```

Based on your sample data, the above returns:

```
jsonb_path_query_array                                                                              
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
[{"location_id": 14555, "remaining_views": 300, "practice_area_id": 39, "monthly_quota_views": 300}]
```

If you are certain there will be only one element matching your condition, you can use `jsonb_path_query_first()` instead